# How do I access the "yes" and "no" keys in my dictionary and put their values in to a list?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()
dir = Path(r'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\somedirectory\pvi_textgrid')
out_file = Path('output.txt')

for file in dir.glob('*.textgrid'):
    with file.open('r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for l in f:
            counter.update(l.strip().split())

counter.most_common(1)

with out_file.open('w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(",".join(counter))
print(counter)
```

output is as such

```py
Counter({'0': 133,
         '""': 73,
         '"IntervalTier"': 57,
         '=': 38,
         '1': 38,
         '3': 35,
         'File': 19,
         'type': 19,
         '"ooTextFile"': 19,
         'Object': 19,
         'class': 19,
         '"TextGrid"': 19,
         '<exists>': 19,
         '"Phonation"': 19,
         '"Speech"': 19,
         '"Comments"': 19,
         '3.93': 14,
         '3.96': 7,
         '5.0200000000000005': 7,
         '3.77': 7,
         '10.21': 7,
         '12.52': 7,
         '11.370000000000001': 7,
         '3.7800000000000002': 7,
         '3.72': 7,
         '12.1': 7,
         '3.97': 7,
         '3.89': 7,
         '5.94': 7,
         '6.2': 7,
         '4.63': 7,
         '4.18': 7,
         '4.62': 7,
         '6.83': 7,
         '"no"': 4,
         '2': 3,
         '0.36100874171044706': 2,
         '1.0890132576679536': 2,
         '0.7216091094277167': 2,
         '1.3713701493710988': 2,
         '0.7099782814647281': 2,
         '1.4161172126881183': 2,
         '0.8348417168127676': 2,
         '3.2335119433221124': 2,
         'five"': 2,
         '1.7299889316602575': 2,
         '2.480568841515854': 2,
         '2.148692441200811': 2,
         '"aa"': 2,
         '2.1688157906233343': 2,
         '1.2904978880596738': 2,
         '0.5533687507723187': 2,
         '0.9558305467454027': 2,
         '0.4383214942352268': 2,
         '0.9760798418291502': 2,
         '0.985814582373786': 2,
         '10.873283112340998': 2,
         '0.7770649427891344': 2,
         '1.1413355432567072': 2,
         '0.5661048087832754': 2,
         '1.0812964186884253': 2,
         '0.7924526404870945': 2,
         '3.11139917918915': 2,
         '0.5212286824463059': 2,
         '3.472996059458859': 2,
         '1.5274624044665293': 2,
         '1.9402683705731323': 2,
         '"yes"': 2,
         '0.991847317448846': 2,
         '1.7480710757789653': 2,
         '0.9602805622853893': 2,
         '2.863884865551033': 2,
         '0.9643968456947999': 2,
         '3.140083120204604': 2,
         '"cancel"': 1,
         '"help"': 1,
         '"quit"': 1,
         '"three': 1,
         'six': 1,
         '"thirty': 1,
         '"ee"': 1,
         '"oo"': 1,
         '"you': 1,
         'wish': 1,
         'to': 1,
         'know': 1,
         'all': 1,
         'about': 1,
         'my': 1,
         'grandfather"': 1,
         '"well': 1,
         'he': 1,
         'is': 1,
         'nearly': 1,
         'ninety': 1,
         'three': 1,
         'years': 1,
         'old"': 1,
         '"eleven': 1,
         'thousand': 1,
         'one"': 1,
         '"oh': 1,
         'zero': 1,
         'ten"': 1})
```

I want to access the "yes" and "no" keys and put their values in to another variable to show the amount of times they are mentioned

Comment: [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the count of words via `counter` :

```py
yes_counts = counter['yes']
no_counts = counter['no']
```

Comment: When I add that code, I only get 0 0 returned

Comment: @FulcyPy Which is obviously due to the fact that the actual keys are not `"yes"`/`"no"` but `'"yes"'`/`'"no"'`.

Comment: I figured it out, thank you